# Verb conjugation in “Chacune et chacun de nous prions notre dieu”

Tags: verbes, accord, conjugaison

I have read the following sentence in a French learning tool:

> Chacune et chacun de nous prions notre dieu

(= Each and every one of us prays to our god)

The verb "prier" is conjugated in the 1st person plural here. I suppose that the verb (oddly) agrees with "de nous". Shouldn't I conjugate in the 3rd person singular, agreeing with "chacune et chacun" (as suggested in http://www.cyjung.com/spip.php?article1805)?

Comment: yes, the agreeing is weird in this sentence; It should be "*...chacun de nous **prie** notre dieu*" if the intended meaning was "*prays*". But because it's *prions* it should be understood as "*let's pray to our god*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepancy can be fixed with proper punctuation:

> *Chacune et chacun d'entre nous, prions notre Dieu !* (let's pray our God).